# No log output with log4net assembly statement inserted - why?

Tags: c#, log4net

In my project, I have a DLL reference which uses log4net internally. In my `Main` class I inserted the following two statements:

```
using log4net;
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

I also prepared an `App.Conf` file.

With only the above, the logging does not start. But when I additionally add the statement

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Main));
```

to my `Main` class, the logging starts and all works fine.

Why do I have to create an `ILog` object to trigger logging to start? Shouldn't the assembly statement with my `App.Conf` file be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time `LogManager.GetLogger` runs, it attempts to determine how log4net is configured. It does this by looking in the **current** assembly for the log4net attribute.

If you do not create a logger in your assembly, then the first time a logger one gets created will be from your referenced dll and hence log4net will look for the log4net attribute in that dll, but won't find it and hence your configuration will be ignored.

By including the line

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Main));
```

in your main application, then this method is run from your exe and log4net will look for the attribute in your exe and this time it finds the attribute and then proceeds to load the correct configuration.

As I understand it, this configuration only takes place the first time GetLogger is called, so it is important to ensure GetLogger is called from your main application first.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This was the point I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always use:

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

That saves you from having to do (typeof(Main)) and you can just cut and paste it into any files that need logging.

I'm confused as to how you were trying to call the logging without creating the "log" object.  What were you trying to do?

I'd probably just use the line of code I gave above.

Comment: Thank you for the nice shortcut. To my problem: A logging object will already be created by the DLL's classes internally. Each class in the reference has its own logger object. So this is why I'm confused to create another one, which has (as far as I see) nothing to do with the logger objects used in the referenced DLL.